# Facebook ads incorrect result or google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, facebook-ads

I have implemented facebook ads which shows my website received 290 link clicks over 2 days , but in my google analytics from the day before I started ad it shows 57 users , why is it so ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why there is a discrepancy between clicks on Facebook Ads (as well as on Google Ads) and Google Analytics sessions. It is a more or less known situation.

Some of these are for example that you are comparing 2 different pieces of information, such as **clicks** on one side and **sessions** or **users** on the other.

Clicks can include clicks on different elements or double clicks.

The session is also detected when the Analytics code on the site page is loaded, so if the user clicks on the ads and exits before the site page is loaded (for example because it loads slowly or because he didn't want to click) you will have clicks counted but not sessions.

In your case you are also talking about *users*, so the discrepancy is certainly higher since if the same person clicks an ads from his smartphone in the morning, then in the afternoon, then in the evening, he will have 3 clicks on Facebook Ads, in the best of cases will result in 3 sessions in Analytics but for the latter it will result in 1 user.

Comment: Thanks a lot but it shows that most of them are unique clicks , it hurts seeing so disparity in performance

Comment: Try to watch sessions if the disparity tapers off a bit

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Michele's answer a couple of points:

- Make sure your cookie banner allow Google Analytics and FB Pixel in the same way (e.g. both are loaded only after the user's acceptance), and make a test also with an AdBlock.
- Try optimising your campaign for **landing page view optimisation**, as they will be counted only those users who click on the ads AND load the page. Maybe this will help.

Edit: be aware about the [iOS14 changes](https://en-gb.facebook.com/business/help/126789292407737?id=428636648170202) that may impact this tracking as well

Comment: yeah landing page view optimisation is required , not link clicks